# is it always true that the riemann sum of a function $f$ is equal to the upper sum over the same partition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $f$ is a bounded function on $I=[a,b]$, and $P$ is a partition of $I$, is it always true that there exists tags of $P$ such that the riemann sum of $f$ on $P$ is equal to the upper sum over the same partition?

If not, could you give me a counter example?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you define the Riemann sum? A definition I know is that a function is called Riemann integrable if and only if for each possible partition, the upper sum and the lower sum converge to the same number.

Comment: same idea as the upper and lower sums, but instead of taking the least or greatest f(x) in an interval, we take arbitrary points

Comment: So if the function is Riemann integrable, all those sums must converge to the same value. If not, well, everything can happen. There are many examples of functions that are not Riemann integrable, e.g. the Dirichlet function $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ else.

Comment: To clarify: you are checking that there is a partition $P$ such that it is possible to choose a set of mid-points $T$ in that partition so that the Riemann sum over $P, T$ is equal to the upper sum? In other words, are you checking that, for any bounded function $f$ on $I$ there is a partition $P$ so that the function actually reaches its supremum (which is then a maximum) on each of the intervals in $P$?

Comment: (If you *are* checking that, the answer is no: take $f(x)=x$ if $x$ irrational, $0$ otherwise, on $[0, 1]$. You cannot reach the supremum $1$ at least on the last interval in $P$ (the one containing $1$).

Comment: What is really true is that given the upper sum $U(f, P)$ we can get a Riemann sum $S(f, P) $ as close to $U(f, P) $ as we wish by a suitable choice of tags.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $f$ such that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [a,b)$ and $f(b)=a$. Then, for a given partition, the upper sum over this partition is strictly greater than any Riemann sum over the same partition: there is no tag $t$ in the last interval on the right $[x_{n-1},b]$ such that $f(t)$ is equal to the supremum of $f$ on that interval, that is $b$.